# how remove ctrl+shift from keyboard settings

Tags: shortcut-keys

[image]

In Keyboard shortcuts -> Next source there is Ctrl+shift
How can I remove this??? Because of this I can't use Ctrl+shift+c or Ctrl+shift+v...

I looked in keyboard settings but only Previous and next source are to be seen, not Ctrl+shift

[image]

UPDATE:
I removed all languages except the English language, and removed keyboard shortcuts... But still as shown in the image, Ctrl+shift is still there...

Is this a bug???

[image]

Comment: On the bottom left of your screenshot, there is a category "Keyboard Shortcuts".  Can you find it there?

Comment: no ... I went through the whole shortcuts but couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

In Keyboard - Shortcuts, click the setting. The "Set shortcut" dialog appears. Now hit Backspace to clear the current key assignment. Press "Set" when done.

Comment: that is what I did... but it only clears the first option (shortcut)..., but not ctrl+shift

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem:
[image]

settings -> keyboard & mouse -> additional layout options
untick Ctrl+Shift

DONE